# Set-valued maps

Tags: analysis

please how to proove that 
$\displaystyle\underline\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n =\bigcap_{\varepsilon>0} \bigcup_{N>0}\bigcap_{n\geq N}(A_n)_\varepsilon $

Comment: What is the $(A_n)_\varepsilon$?

Comment: is the $\varepsilon$-neighborhood of the set $A_n$

Comment: $x \in (A_n)_\varepsilon \Leftrightarrow d(x,A_n) < \varepsilon$

Comment: $\displaystyle\underline\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n =\lbrace x\in E, \displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}d(x,A_n)=0 \rbrace$, $(E,d)$ is a metric space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f_n(x)=d(x,A_n)$. By def,
$$\varliminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n =\{x\in E : \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=0\}$$
and take
$$U(n,\varepsilon)=\{x\in E : |f_n(x)|<\varepsilon\}.$$
So
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=0 \iff \forall\varepsilon\exists N \forall n>N: |f_n(x) |<\varepsilon \iff \forall\varepsilon\exists N \forall n>N: x\in U(n,\varepsilon).$$
By definition of arbitary intersection, we get
$$\forall n>N : x\in U_n \iff x\in \bigcap _{n>N}U_n$$
and we get
$$ x\in \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=0 \iff \forall\varepsilon\exists N :  x\in \bigcap _{n>N}U(n,\varepsilon).$$
and by definition of arbitary union
$$\bigcup_{A\in S} A=\{x|\exists A\in S:x\in A\},$$
we obtain
$$\forall\varepsilon\exists N :  x\in \bigcap _{n>N}U(n,\varepsilon) \iff \forall\varepsilon: x\in \bigcup_{N>0} \bigcap _{n>N}U(n,\varepsilon)$$
and use def. of arbitary intersection again, we get
$$\forall\varepsilon: x\in \bigcup_{N>0} \bigcap _{n>N}U(n,\varepsilon) \iff  x\in \bigcap_{\varepsilon>0}\bigcup_{N>0} \bigcap _{n>N}U(n,\varepsilon)$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** use the definition of "$\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\displaystyle\lim_{\quad \quad n\rightarrow \infty}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\mbox{-inf} A_n$" :
$$
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\displaystyle\lim_{\quad \quad n\rightarrow \infty}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\mbox{-inf} A_n=\bigcup_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{n>N} A_n
$$
and the fact
$$
A_n\subset (A_n)_\epsilon \implies \bigcup_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{n>N} A_n\subset \bigcup_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{n>N} (A_n)_\epsilon.
$$
for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Please , how can i proov this ? $\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\displaystyle\lim_{\quad \quad n\rightarrow \infty}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\mbox{-inf} A_n=\bigcup_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{n>N} A_n$

Comment: $\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\displaystyle\lim_{\quad \quad n\rightarrow \infty}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\mbox{-inf} A_n$ is a notation for  $\displaystyle\underline\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} A_n$.

Comment: yes i known ...

Comment: @kiroro You can prove $A_n\subset (A_n)_\epsilon$ usign the definition of $(A_n)_\epsilon$. And using the definitions of  $\bigcap$ and $\bigcup$ for conclude $A_n\subset (A_n)_\epsilon \implies \bigcup_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{n>N} A_n\subset \bigcup_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{n>N} (A_n)_\epsilon$.